# Is it possible to use the managedCUDA wrapper to run parallel computations from a Unity C# script?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, cuda

I'm trying to work out the best way to make calls to CUDA code from a Unity C# script.

The [managedCUDA](http://managedcuda.codeplex.com/) project seems the best way to wrap a C# interface to the CUDA kernels, but would this work if the C# script was compiled by Unity?

Any insight here would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do something very complicated I would prefer to use a [Computer Shader](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ComputeShaders.html) which is available and built in Unity. Compute shaders are basically programs that run on the graphics card, outside of the normal rendering pipeline. The only draw back is you need to know about shader programming (HLSL) which is not C# unfortuately. There is a nice tutorial [here](http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/2014/06/27/Compute-Shaders-Are-Nifty.html).

Cuda (and managedCUDA) use exactly the same approach, compile and run a program written in C (or C#) language in the GPU, using compute shaders.

Otherwise you can add external c# library to your project, just add the dlls from managedCUDA to you asset folder, and reference them in your solution. Then run your cuda code from the Start method of your Unity script.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not convinced this is a good option for me, i'm comfortable with CUDA already and my heavy computation is in no way relating to a graphics problem, In-fact im doing some audio processing, i doubt that trying formulate the algorthim into shader programming language would be an optimal use of time, unless i was already fluent in it. I also want to perform FFT/IFFT on GPU and CUDA supports this.

Comment: I edited my answer. in theory what you do in a cuda kernel is the same you would do in a compute shader  but I see the learning curve might be steep to learn HLSL.

Comment: Excellent so this means it is possible.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this suggestion. I tried to use managedCuda and Cudafy, but both seem to have to marshall/unmarshall data when bringing it to the GPU. This has a significant overhead for me. Is it possible to run a vertex or fragment shader inside a ComputeShader?

Comment: @AlexS: If you use managedCuda or Cudafy be aware of the problem I stated. On my computer it will incur a latency of at least 5-100 ms depending on my data size.